# How can I restore my garment's colour after I washed it with black colours?

Tags: color, washing

I have got a 100% cotton dark blue and light blue pyjama on 40 degrees. I just washed its top with my black T-shirts. It clearly became darker because I can compare it with the trousers. Is there a way to restore its brightness? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One has to ask how essential it is that a pair of pyjamas doesn't take on a darker hue – few people will know or even care. The easiest solution is to write it off to experience, and be thankful it wasn't a garment that really matters, such as your best white shirt turning pink after washing with a red T-shirt.

My simple **hack** is to:

- Wash just the bottom part with some black T-shirts, to even it up with the top.

Then in the future:

- Always wash both parts together, so their colours stay the same.
- Wash dark and light clothes separately, especially those with strong colour.